# How to add Multiple Flutter Framework in iOS App

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, ios-frameworks

In our native application, flutter framework is already added. We created a new module in flutter and want to add in the same application. We are getting exception while adding the framework.

Is there any way to change the generated flutter framework name, from App.framework to TestApp.framework.
Or any other way to add same framework?